# What is the difference between geometry and geometryZ?

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I saw some databases in Postgres/PostGIS which contains 2 different fields types:

```
geometry
```

and

```
geometry(GeometryZ)
```

- What is the different between those 2 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one accepts a 2d coordinates `Point ( x y)` the other 3d coordinates `Point ( x y z)`

There are also 4d coordinates in postgis

https://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/3d.html